# How estimate Current Consumption In minutes reference

Tags: current

Hello I hope somebody can give a short answer. 
I am confused about how estimate the current consumption of a Electronic Component/device. For example a led 20ma @ 3V or an arduino mini @ 50ma.
If I use 3 led the current draw is 60ma so in a battery of 2850mAh the leds can be power on 47.5 hours, right?. 
I am confused when I want to estimate how much hours can be running the 3 leds if they are power on only each 15 minutes for two minutes, then turn off... And so on. I mean, for example, turn on at 15.15 and turn off 15.17, then turn on 15.30 and turn off 15.32 etc... I think in 1 hour the leds power on 4 times for total 8 minutes so the current consumption is 60mAh*(8/60) ???
In a 2850mAh battery the real life of my leds can be 2850mAh/(60mA*(8/60) = 322.5 hours ???

I am totally wrong?

Thanks you very much

Comment: Yes. If the circuit is on for only two minutes at a time, and four times per hour, then this means 8 minutes out of each 60 minutes. So 8/60 is about 13.3% of the time. If keeping all three LEDs on for an hour would consume 60 mAh, then keeping them on for 13.3% of that time would consume 8mAh. Of course, if your circuit isn't ***completely*** off the rest of the time, you should include what little it uses because even if the amount is small it is multiplied by a lot of time. Make sure you account for all the bits. Also, batteries have different figures depending upon loading. So watch that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I could estimate the real life of small project running with 3.7 lion battery :)

Comment: You can also get brighter LEDs and run them at 2mA minimum.

Comment: Ooh where, what is the part number? The true is I need to estimate the consumption of arduino mini pro project with GSM module and sensor. Led was only a computing example